# From a bare minimum Ubuntu to something like an AWS Ubuntu standard image

Tags: 12.04, server, configuration, amazon-ec2

If I am given a bare minimum ubuntu machine in a private cloud environment with almost nothing installed on it(not even apt-get and ubuntu repositories configured) and the only user is root, what are the set of commands to run to turn this machine as configured as an ec2 standard ubuntu 12.04 image? One can find these commands here and there but I am looking for something that induces all I need to run to have a properly configuration machine as good as the amazon ubuntu ami.

Comment: Do you have access to the coreutils? wget, and such? what commands are actually available?

Answer (score 2):

That is a tough one. I can not provide "the set of commands", but describe how I would approach this task.

.deb packages have `priority`'s. Most of the packages have the priority `optional`, but the ones that are interesting here are the packages with `required`, `important` and `standard` priority. Those are the ones that are usually installed on every system. `apt-get` is one of them. You could scan the `Packages` file of the `main` repository for a list of all packages that are `required` and `important` priority, download all the .deb files and install them with dpkg -i. (I sincerely hope you do not have to bootstrap dpkg!) Then you should have a functional apt system. Then you should be able to use `aptitude` in order to install all `standard` packages. Done that you could install the task `server` with `tasksel`.

[Packages file for amd64](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2)

Good luck